# Unique enum member values

Tags: java, enums

My problem: I want to specify a 1 to 1 connection between two enums. basically:

```
enum MyEnum{

    ENUM_VALUE_1,
    ENUM_VALUE_2,
    ENUM_VALUE_3,

}

enum MyOtherEnum{

    OTHER_ENUM_VALUE_1(MyEnum.ENUM_VALUE_3),
    OTHER_ENUM_VALUE_2(MyEnum.ENUM_VALUE_1),
    OTHER_ENUM_VALUE_3,
    OTHER_ENUM_VALUE_4(MyEnum.ENUM_VALUE_2),

    private MyEnum pair;

    MyOtherEnum(MyEnum pair){
        this.pair=pair;
    }

}
```

Given this code, what is the best way to make sure, that two instances of `MyOtherEnum` doesn't have the same `MyEnum` pair? I figured some solutions, but neither seem to be good. One solution is throw an exception in the constructor, but I'm not sure if that is even doable. Another solution is a special getter method, but it can be easily bypassed with simple `MyOtherEnum.values()` calls.

Comment: WTH? Why? please tell us some context, this looks suspicious. Also see: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: `what is the best way to make sure` You're writing the source code, just look at it.

Comment: There are two enums from two different places, and this attachment can keep me from 200 cases in a switch.

Comment: Attila, please clarify this: you want to ensure that there is no pair in `MyOtherEnum` values having the same `MyEnum` attribute? Or you want to check if 2 given instances of `MyOtherEnum` share the same attribute?

Comment: It's more of an interesting quiestion rather than an important one. It probably can save some headache for someone years later. You never know. I want to specify this connection as a one to one(or zero) connection.

Comment: @AttilaNeparáczki I'm sure there is a better solution to your real problem, as i understand it you want to simplify a switch. Why don't you explain that problem and we could try to solve it in a better way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you shouldn't implement this as a runtime check. It can only fail if a developer who has control over the code did some bad changes. Detecting changes that introduce bugs is what tests are for.

Write a simple test that checks if everything is correct. The other answers already provide some good solutions to check for duplicated enums. Instead of running the application to see if the enum initialisation fails, run the test (I hope you already write and run tests anyway).

Answer (score 2):

I put the "why" aside and try to answer your question:

Create a static block in `MyOtherEnum` that performs the check:

```
static{
    // This set stores all the used values
    EnumSet<MyEnum> usedValues = EnumSet.noneOf(MyEnum.class);

    for(MyOtherEnum e : values()){
        // Value already present in the set?
        if(usedValues.contains(e.pair)) throw ...; // Duplicate 
        usedValues.add(e);
    }
}
```

But I have to agree with the comments: Instead of writing this check, you can also simply look at your code :).

Comment: This is perfect, if the static block gets executed after the enum instances are contructed. Which I suppose is the case, since your solution is based on that.

Comment: @AttilaNeparáczki: Usually, all static stuff in Java is initialized in the order it appears in the file. Since enum constants are before all static initializers, this works.

Comment: Throwing exceptions from static initialisers is troublesome.

Comment: I see. This solution never would've come to my mind.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Since enum instance constructors are called from the enum class static initializer, your answer does the same thing (albeit indirectly).

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
public enum MyEnum {

    ENUM_VALUE_1,
    ENUM_VALUE_2,
    ENUM_VALUE_3,

}

// All enums taken.
private static final Set<MyEnum> taken = EnumSet.noneOf(MyEnum.class);

enum MyOtherEnum {

    OTHER_ENUM_VALUE_1(MyEnum.ENUM_VALUE_3),
    OTHER_ENUM_VALUE_2(MyEnum.ENUM_VALUE_1),
    OTHER_ENUM_VALUE_3(MyEnum.ENUM_VALUE_2),
    OTHER_ENUM_VALUE_4(MyEnum.ENUM_VALUE_2);

    private MyEnum pair;

    MyOtherEnum(MyEnum pair) {
        if (taken.contains(pair)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot pair the same MyEnum with two other enums! " + this);
        }
        taken.add(pair);
        this.pair = pair;
    }

}

public void test() {
    System.out.println("Hello: " + MyOtherEnum.OTHER_ENUM_VALUE_4);
}
```

Comment: I meant exactly what you provided :D My colleages suggested it's bad practice to throw exceptions inside constructors, so I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: I was also thinking about this, but it seems useless to me. I mean, an enum is a closed set of instances for the given type, which is solely under the programmer's control. The programmer declares the values, so he is up to configure them properly. There's no other interaction he should protect his code from. There's nobody else who could add instances to the type. So why the extra verification in constructor?

Comment: @AndreiNicusan - I am all for making it difficult to code it wrong.

Comment: @Andrei Nicusan: that’s exactly what *assertions* are for. They include checks that ought to be obsolete if everything is coded correctly.

Comment: @Holger totally agree with you guys, I only wanted to stress out that the piece of code that does the checking (i.e. the constructor) is 1 line of code away from the code that might break the rule (i.e. the enum values declaration).

Comment: @AndreiNicusan - There could be hundreds of entries in each `enum` - a much more difficult situation to visually check.

Comment: @Andrei Nicusan: a few lines away but look at the example: the constants are hard to tell apart as they differ in one character only, and there is one important thing to consider: *copy&paste*, the infamous programming tool…

Answer (score 0):

Im a bit confused, by your question. Have you considered using [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)?

A [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) can be used to ensure unique values, then simply add the values used in the [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) if it returns false the value already exists.

Comment: That is true, a EnumSet should be used in this case.

Comment: The question is about where to put the check, not how to implement it.

Comment: Not according to the question: "Given this code, what is the best way to make sure, that two instances of MyOtherEnum doesn't have the same MyEnum pair?"

Please update the question, since it obviously isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static block to test your linkage:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class EnumTrick {
  enum MyEnum {
    ENUM_VALUE_1, ENUM_VALUE_2, ENUM_VALUE_3,
  }

  enum MyOtherEnum {

    OTHER_ENUM_VALUE_1(MyEnum.ENUM_VALUE_3), 
    OTHER_ENUM_VALUE_2(MyEnum.ENUM_VALUE_1),
    OTHER_ENUM_VALUE_3(MyEnum.ENUM_VALUE_2), 
    OTHER_ENUM_VALUE_4(MyEnum.ENUM_VALUE_2);


    private MyEnum pair;

    MyOtherEnum(MyEnum pair) {
      this.pair = pair;

    }

    static {
      Set<MyEnum> usedEnums = new HashSet<MyEnum>();
      for(MyOtherEnum moe : MyOtherEnum.values()){
        if(! usedEnums.add(moe.pair) ){
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(moe.pair + " is already used!");
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String [] args){
    MyOtherEnum moe = MyOtherEnum.OTHER_ENUM_VALUE_1;
  }
}
```

Will throw an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at EnumTrick.main(EnumTrick.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ENUM_VALUE_2 is already used!
  at EnumTrick$MyOtherEnum.<clinit>(EnumTrick.java:28)
  ... 1 more
```