# How to ensure that enum field values are unique?

Tags: java, enums

Suppose you have a, say, integer field in an enum and you want to ensure that each enum constant has a unique field value. How would you go about that?

Comment: Actually, yeah - what does this Q/A add that's not covered by the existing question + answers?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That question is regarding a 1-1 correspondence between constants in two enum types. In terms of the answer, that answer is only applicable when dealing with the other enum type.

Answer (score 0):

Use a static initializer (inspired by [Unique enum member values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831903/unique-enum-member-values#23832081)):

```
enum MyEnum {
    CONST_1(5); //...
    private int code;
    public MyEnum(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    } 
    public int getCode() {
        return this.code;
    } // ...

    static {
        // check that the codes are unique.
        if (Arrays.stream(MyEnum.values()).map(MyEnum::getCode).distinct()
            .count() != MyEnum.values().length)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Codes aren't unique.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `static` block *guaranteed* to execute after the all the enum values have been initialized?

Comment: I think that it is not something that should be done at runtime. Unit tests are designed to assert this kind of things. You do that for enums but you could also check multiple others things. Runtime code is not testing code. If used structures don't provide the required check, I write a unit test.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I just tried it and it worked. But, I would need to examine the spec more carefully.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I think it does, because the enum values are basically `public static final MyEnum CONST_1 = new MyEnum(5);`, and that appears lexically before the static initializer. [JLS Sec 8.9.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3).

Comment: @AndyTurner / Raffi - yeah, I think you're correct.  But I'm always a little nervous about relying on that kind of thing, not least because it's so easily to accidentally break by simply refactoring one's code :/  (Either way, it would be good to add a citation to this answer!)

Comment: Please help me understand the concept. What do you mean by `enum` field with unique value? I still can write like `CONST_1(5),
 CONST_12(5);` where value is same.

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik That will cause the exception to be thrown.